# Mount remote windows harddrive

Tags: linux, windows, mount, remote, hard-drive

Alright,

this hard drive that I need to mount is on a windows machine, in a different town.

What would be the best approach for this?

I would like it in fstab if possible, and a little bit of encryption would be nice too.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

when you say mount it...

you could use CIFS (or SAMBA) to share it on the remote windows computer and mount it (even via your fstab if you like) on the linux box.

A quick VPN tunnel in the middle should offer you a level of encryption.

Its probably worth clarifying your question a little. What are you trying to do with the drive once its 'mounted'?

Comment: this is for a lumber mill. The server is to have all the harddrives of remote saws and laser guides, so the designers can simply login on the server and store files in the proper location without having several logins etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [smbfs](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/165).